# How can I check that my application is shutdown with QFTest?

Tags: python, java, jython, javaagents, qf-test

I check a Java application with **QFTest**. I need to prove that the HMI is stopped at Shutdown.
In **QFTest**, I created a **Jython** procédure which try to send a socket to the HMI, if it can't, then it means that the HMI is stopped and then the test is OK. here is the **jython** script:

```
import threading
import time

rc.setLocal("returnValue", False)
for i in range(50):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    try:
        # here we try to send a socket to HMI
        rc.toSUT("client", vars)
    except:
        # here there was an exception trying to send the socket, the HMI is shutdown: test OK."
        rc.setLocal("returnValue", True)
        break
```

It seems that the **QFTest** **javaagent** used to connect my Java program to **QFTest**, prevents my application to be fully killed. Have you an idea to prove that my HMI is killed in a **QFTest** procedure ?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid any communication with the SUT while shutting down. QF-Tests tries to stop the application gracefully, if you record a sequence for the steps a user would do. There are also the dedicated nodes  Additionally you may try to kill the SUT-client. For example of such a construct look in the procedure startStop.terminate from the demo suite delivered with QF-Test under <qftest_isntall_dir>\demo\carconfig\carconfig_en.qft.

If the problem persist you should write to the QF-Test support, since additional details my be required, and the stackoverflow.com is not suitable for such communcation.

Disclaimer: I am a QF-Test Employee